# Numpy's `meshgrid` is discontinuously slow

Tags: python, numpy, performance

Over repeated calls to `meshgrid` I realized it can become slow at some sample sizes for no seemingly apparent reason. For example, in this snippet:

```py
from time import time
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1729)

maxn  = 760
times = np.empty(maxn+1)
times[0] = time()
for n in range(1, maxn+1):
    x = np.random.uniform(size=(n,1))
    y = np.random.uniform(size=(n,1))
    x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    times[n] = time()

last = 40
[f'{i+maxn-last+1}: {x:.3f}' for i, x in enumerate(np.diff(times)[-last:])]
```

I get

```py
['721: 0.003',
 '722: 0.003',
 '723: 0.003',
 '724: 0.004',
 '725: 0.010',
 '726: 0.007',
 '727: 0.007',
 '728: 0.005',
 '729: 0.005',
 '730: 0.006',
 '731: 37.243', # Suddenly slow
 '732: 0.009',
 '733: 0.007',
 '734: 0.007',
 '735: 0.009',
 '736: 0.007',
 '737: 0.009',
 '738: 0.009',
 '739: 0.009',
 '740: 11.602', # Suddenly slow
 '741: 0.008',
 '742: 0.010',
 '743: 0.012',
 '744: 0.012',
 '745: 0.016',
 '746: 0.009',
 '747: 0.015',
 '748: 0.015',
 '749: 61.460', # Suddenly slow
 '750: 0.008',
 '751: 0.007',
 '752: 0.007',
 '753: 0.007',
 '754: 0.007',
 '755: 0.007',
 '756: 0.007',
 '757: 0.007',
 '758: 1.167', # Suddenly slow
 '759: 0.007',
 '760: 0.010']
```

You can see most runs are instantaneous, but suddenly one particular run has a very slow runtime (weirdly in this case it's every 9th run, starting in 731). Not sure what's a maxn that will yield this phenomenon in other machines, though. Any thoughts on what might be happening?

Python version 3.10.10 and numpy version 1.24.2 on Arch Linux.

**EDIT2:** I decided to use a workaround in place of `meshgrid`, which seems to work for my use case:

```py
x_grid, y_grid = np.broadcast_arrays(x[:, np.newaxis], y[np.newaxis, :])
x_grid = x_grid.reshape((x.shape[0], y.shape[0])).T
y_grid = y_grid.reshape((x.shape[0], y.shape[0])).T
```

**EDIT:** I wan the snippet with `perf stat` and am posting the results here. The slowdowns happened at different places, interestingly.

```
721: 0.003
722: 0.003
723: 0.003
724: 0.004
725: 0.008
726: 0.009
727: 0.008
728: 0.009
729: 0.014
730: 0.015
731: 0.013
732: 0.009
733: 0.009
734: 16.755
735: 0.012
736: 0.011
737: 0.011
738: 0.011
739: 0.013
740: 0.010
741: 0.010
742: 0.013
743: 0.011
744: 22.704
745: 0.016
746: 0.012
747: 0.017
748: 0.016
749: 0.016
750: 0.012
751: 0.011
752: 0.016
753: 4.244
754: 0.018
755: 0.014
756: 0.018
757: 0.015
758: 0.017
759: 0.021
760: 0.018

 Performance counter stats for 'python test.py':

         45,125.79 msec task-clock:u                     #    0.998 CPUs utilized             
                 0      context-switches:u               #    0.000 /sec                      
                 0      cpu-migrations:u                 #    0.000 /sec                      
           568,187      page-faults:u                    #   12.591 K/sec                     
     1,150,132,500      cycles:u                         #    0.025 GHz                       
     1,124,532,475      instructions:u                   #    0.98  insn per cycle            
       188,859,225      branches:u                       #    4.185 M/sec                     
         3,959,138      branch-misses:u                  #    2.10% of all branches           

      45.194501699 seconds time elapsed

       0.393526000 seconds user
      44.537625000 seconds sys
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this - all runs are taking more or less the same amount of time.

Comment: @NickODell Then it might be an issue with my machine specifically... That's sad news for me.

Comment: Can't reproduce either. All runs take 0.003 + or - 0.001. Running Python 3.10, numpy 1.23, on Ubuntu 22.

Comment: I can reproduce this on my machine, Mac Intel python 3.8.5, numpy 1.21.2

Comment: I also cannot reproduce this with CPython 3.8.1 and Numpy 1.22.4 on Windows 10. I wonder if it is actually due to Numpy or something else. A >2000x slower execution is generally not due to basic computations especially when the timings are so unstable. RAM/Cache effects and more specifically thrashing can significantly slow down the execution but x2000 is really huge even for that... We need profiling information to help you further. Can you run this with `perf stat` and report the result? Besides are results deterministic? What happen if you run this 5 times with `n` set to 731?

Comment: @JérômeRichard I ran the original script with `perf stat` and posted the results. It's also not deterministic: I ran this 5 times with n=731 and only got the slowdown twice. Once for ~2s and another time for ~86s. The original snippet also slows down at different iterations in different runs. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. The results suggest that the CPU is waiting during nearly all the time, or operate at a very low frequency (or even halted), or the Python process is de-scheduled. The later is the most probable since Numpy do not perform any blocking things like IO operations (I assume you operate on a bare metal system with 1 user and no other intensive computing processes). I think the only syscall that could cause this is a memmap due to allocations. The process may also be interrupt though 0 context-switches are reported which is very suspicious for a so long process stalling (impossible?).

Comment: I guess perf is not configured to have access to kernel data on your machine and this is why we see that. A deeper profiling is needed to understand the source of these stall. Unfortunately, it will not be simple to do since I cannot reproduce the problem. The syscalls can be tracked with `strace`. `perf stat -a` can be used to track the whole system including the kernel if it has the rights. Looking `perf top` while there is a stall can be interesting here to see what functions are running during stalls (including the kernel).

Comment: `perf sched` is the way to go to understand why the process is descheduled, assuming it is. Unfortunately, this is not so easy to use (generating bad traces is very easy) and produce a significant amount of data hard to understand for people not used to read it. This tool let you see what the OS scheduler does, kernel threads and IO events (i.e. precious informations).

Comment: @JérômeRichard I can't use `perf stat -a` without editing some kernel parameters, apparently. If I try to use `perf sched` then I get an error that `sched` is not a `perf` command. (Even though I have a man entry for it.) Is it safe to enable `perf_event_paranoid`? PS: I'm now using `np.broadcast_arrays` + a reshape, which works instantaneously. However, if I use `column_stack` on the results (instead of a reshape) I'm back to being arbitrarily slow sometimes. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Mauricio: Note that `np.broadcast_arrays` is fast because it just builds views of the input, and for that to work, the views have to have heavy internal aliasing - many cells of the resulting arrays map to the same memory location. This is fine for read-only use cases, but if you want to write to the results, it's not going to be enough.

Comment: The `reshape` also builds a view. `column_stack` does not, which is probably why you see the slowdowns that way.

Comment: @Mauricio Changing `perf_event_paranoid` in `/proc/sys/` only affect the kernel state for the current boot, this parameter will be reset when the machine is restarted. Setting it to 0 is quite safe if you do not run web-server or similar applications that could have some vulnerability and be significantly exposed. A low value can be used by attacker to do side channel attack and even track some kernel calls if the value is -1. Unless a hacker is operating on your machine, I do not expect this to be used by any malware since it is not enabled by default.

Comment: @Mauricio A basic PC tends not to be exposed and setting the value to 0 is relatively safe on most machines. If a hacker is operating on your machine, the value of `perf_event_paranoid` is certainly the least of your problem ;) . I advise to reset the value once the profiling is done though so to be safer. This is a parameter for "paranoid" people after all ;) . For `perf sched`, it certainly need root privileged because it tracks the OS scheduler operations.